# move to multiple activities according to JSON data

Tags: android

I have a some JSON Data -

```
{
"ActivityOrder":[
{
"Position":3,
"ActivityName":"Activity1"
},
{
"Position":5,
"ActivityName":"Activity2"
},
{
"Position":2,
"ActivityName":"Activity3"
},
{
"Position":1,
"ActivityName":"Activity4"
},
{
"Position":4,
"ActivityName":"Activity5"
}
]
}
```

According to above JSON data, call Intent from Single Activity or class. I mean First call Position1 activity (Activity4), then position2 (Activity3) and so on.

Note:- In JSON Data, Activity Position can be changed from backend.

Comment: parse json and store in pojo model. Then sort model by Position key

Comment: is activity name will change from backend

Comment: @DivyeshPatel - position key may be changed...

Comment: @AbhinavGupta - name not changed but activityName's position will changed

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you get your activity name , create the class like this :

```
Class activity= Class.forName("yourActivityName");
```

And then create the intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create pojo model class:

```
public class MyPojo {

    String  ActivityName;
    int  Position;

    public MyPojo(String activityName, int position) {
        ActivityName = activityName;
        Position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return Position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        Position = position;
    }

    public String getActivityName() {
        return ActivityName;
    }

    public void setActivityName(String activityName) {
        ActivityName = activityName;
    }
}
```

Now parse json to Model:

```
List<MyPojo> MyPojoList=new ArrayList<>();

    try {

            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("your json response");
            JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("ActivityOrder");
            for (int i=0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                 String Position = jObj.getString("Position");
                 String ActivityName = jObj.getString("ActivityName");
                 MyPojoList.add(new MyPojo(ActivityName,Position));
            }

        }
        catch(JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now sort array :

```
Collections.sort(MyPojoList, new Comparator<MyPojo>(){
            public int compare(MyPojo obj1, MyPojo obj2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(obj1.getPosition()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(obj2.getPosition()));
            }
        });
```

Finally, start the activity with position one by one:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyPojoList.get(position).getActivityName()));
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```